# How can I use modulous to convert seconds into hours minutes and seconds?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, joptionpane

My teacher assigned me this homework, and her prompt is " Write a program that allows the user to enter the number of seconds.The program should calculate the equivalent number of hours, minutes and seconds.  Example:  9999 seconds = 2 hours, 46 minutes, and 39 seconds. Mod is your freind. I am trying to use JOptionPane with this.

Ive tried a lot of other ways, yet none of them work. When I put in 2, it results as 2 hours.

I expect when I put in 2 it results as 2 seconds, not hours!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you want to do something like this:
Given n seconds, var hours, var minutes, var seconds

```
seconds = n%60;
minutes = (n-seconds)%3600;
//we use subtract seconds that have already been allocated
//Mod by 3600 here because this is the number of seconds in 1 hour, so the remainder will not fit into an hour
minutes = minutes/60; //convert seconds to minutes
hours = (n - minutes*60 - seconds) / 3600; //seconds remaining/seconds in an hour
```

This solution works using mod and should work for 2 seconds. You may need to add some conditional IF statements to make sure you don't get a failure dividing 0 though.